# Is there a way to insert mathematical expressions into an SVG's XML?

Tags: svg, xml, mathematics

I'm wondering if it is at all possible to edit an SVG's XML so that `M 36, 187 H 61.455844` can be more precisely calculated.

I tried `M 36, 187 H (36+18*sqrt(2))` to see if that would work, though unfortunately not; I don't know whether is is possible to insert mathematical expressions as coordinate points, though I hope it is, so that I can rely on preprocessing to give me as much precision as my machine can handle.

Comment: SVG has no way of calculating things like that. But any real programming language can generate a string with those calculations, i.e. you output a string that can be interpreted as SVG.

Comment: I guess technically you could include a script tag in your SVG and do JS there. But whether or not that can actually run depends on the environment. It's definitely safer to do it beforehand.